# draft-js Editor only display native emojis

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

after getting the `contentState` from server and "converting From Raw"
Im displaying it inside an Editor and it shows only the native emojis.

event though that before sending it to the server, the chat editor displayed the emojis right

this is the process

```
    const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(comment.message))
    const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState)
    <ChatTemplate 
                  user={currentUser === comment.userId} 
                  value={editorState} 
                  time={moment(comment.createdAt).startOf('second').fromNow()} />
```

and the editor

```
  const ChatTemplate = (p)=>(
       <div className='globalMassage-cont' data-user={p.user} >
         <div className='globalMassage-value'>
           <Editor
             editorState={p.value}
             plugins={plugins}
             readOnly
            />
         </div>
       </div>
     )
```

the imports and constants

```
import Editor, { createEditorStateWithText } from "draft-js-plugins-editor";
import createEmojiPlugin from "draft-js-emoji-plugin";
import { EditorState, ContentState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";
const emojiPlugin = createEmojiPlugin();
const { EmojiSuggestions, EmojiSelect } = emojiPlugin;
const plugins = [emojiPlugin];
```